# Wireshark look for tcp sessions with no valid http response

Tags: wireshark

I want to filter a trace to show http requests (posts or gets) which did not get a 200 response. By this I mean not just filter on http.response.code, I mean if there was no response at all from the server (no response code) or other type of response (e.g. server rejected connection following http request) for the http request. Can this be done in wireshark or do I need another tool to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The http dissector has a field called 'http.response_in' which specifies the frame number containing response to a particular http request.

I think a display filter something like the following will show just http "Get" request frames which have no response frame in the capture.

http.request.method == "GET" && !http.response_in